# SPARQL Query gives unexpected result

Tags: python, rdf, sparql, rdflib

I hope someone can help me on this probably totally easy-to-solve problem:

I want to run a SPARQL query against the following RDF (noted in N3, the RDF/XMl sits [here](http://rdf.schalljugend.net/umstaetter.rdf)). This is the desription of a journal article and descriptions of the journal, author and publisher:

```
 @prefix bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> .
 @prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
 @prefix ex: <http://example.org/thesis/> .
 @prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
 @prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<ex:XY>     a bibo:Article;
     dc:creator ex:umstaetter;
     dc:date "2008-11-01";
     dc:isPartOf ex:bibdienst;
     dc:title "DDC in Europa"@de;
     bibo:endPage "1221";
     bibo:issue "11";
     bibo:language "de";
     bibo:pageStart "1194";
     bibo:uri <http://www.zlb.de/Erschliessung020309BD.pdf>;
     bibo:volume "42" .

<ex:bibdienst>     a bibo:Journal;
     dc:publisher ex:zlb;
     dc:title "Bibliotheksdienst"@de;
     bibo:issn "00061972" .

<ex:umstaetter>     a foaf:person;
     foaf:birthday "1941-06-12";
     foaf:gender "Male";
     foaf:givenName "Walther";
     foaf:homepage <http://www.ib.hu-berlin.de/~wumsta/index.html>;
     foaf:img "http://libreas.eu/ausgabe7/pictures/wumstaetter1.jpg";
     foaf:name "Walther Umst\u00E4tter";
     foaf:surname "Umst\u00E4tter";
     foaf:title "Prof. Dr. rer. nat." .

<ex:zlb>     a foaf:Organization;
     foaf:homepage <http://www.zlb.de>;
     foaf:name "Zentral- und Landesbibliothek Berlin"@de .
```

For testing purposes I wanted to read out the **foaf:homepage** of **ex:zlb** - the SPARQL I want to run is:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/thesis/>

SELECT ?article ?publisher ?publisher_url
WHERE 
{
    ?article dc:isPartOf ?journal .
    ?journal dc:publisher ?publisher .
    ?publisher foaf:homepage ?publisher_url
}
```

(Again: This is gonna be for testing only since there is only one entity of article.)

Running it on my local machine with Python and RDflib doesn't give me a result. Neither does the Online Redland SPARQL Query Demo.

Anyone out there who sees a solution? Am I on the right path or totally wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that you can use a QName in an XML attribute value; e.g. the value of `rdf:about`.  So consider this line from your RDF/XML file:

```
 <bibo:Journal rdf:about="ex:bibdienst">
```

I think that this is actually saying that the subject URI is "ex:bibdienst".  That is a syntactically valid URI, but it is not the same URI as appears as the object of the triple corresponding to this line:

```
 <dc:isPartOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/thesis/bibdienst" />
```

Try replacing the QNames in XML attribute values with the corresponding URIs and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Perfect. That fixed my problem. Somehow I got confused about what is allowed in XML and N3 and what not :) THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 6):

Yep Stephen C is totally correct that you can't use QNames in XML attributes, you can use XML entities instead which you define in a DTD block at the top of your document like so:

eg.

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF[
    <!ENTITY rdf 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
    <!ENTITY rdfs 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'>
    <!ENTITY xsd 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'>
    <!ENTITY ex 'http://example.org/thesis/'>
    <!ENTITY dc 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'>
    <!ENTITY foaf 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/'>
    <!ENTITY bibo 'http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/'>
]>
```

Then you can define attributes like so:

```
<bibo:Journal rdf:about="&ex;bibdienst">
```

Comment: THANKS for the suggestion. I'll try that one out (I indeed always wondered what the "&[prefix];" in XML meant. thanks to you it's now totally clear to me). THANKS A LOT!